# Is it possible Animate the Compositor node parameters?

Tags: compositing-nodes

In blender compositor Ineed to animate some Node parametors like Transform, Colore curve, Set alpha values etc.. **Is it possible Animate the Compositor node parameters?**

Answer (score 11):

Of course. As (almost) everywhere in blender:

1. Insert a keyframe by placing the cursor over a property and press <kbd>`I`</kbd>
2. Move to a different frame in the timeline
3. Set the property to the desired value
4. Press <kbd>`I`</kbd> again for a second keyframe on this property

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can just *right click* on (almost) any property and choose *Insert Keyframe*:

[image]

Dopesheet & Graph Editor:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd> removes a single keyframe, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`I`</kbd> removes all keyframes of a property.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just right click on (almost) any property and choose *Insert Keyframe*.

Comment: the key you press in 1) , is it an uppercase i, lowercase L or pipe-symbol | ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred It's lowercase i (insert).