# How to start a Time Node?

Tags: animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes, timeline

[image]

**my goal:**

This is my first compositing attempt in Blender, my goal is to create an animation shown in the render window, the animation is a simple shift from one colour to another within about 100 frames.

**what I did and thought:**

To achieve this, I put a composite node for displaying the rendering, I took two RGB-nodes, each with a different colour, and connected them into a mixer. In order to obtain a shift from one colour to the other I connected the time-node into the fac-input of the mixer. The time node is set to a frame range from 1 to 100 frames, I thought the time-node would automatically go from frame 1 to frame 100 once it is connected to the mixer, yet in reality the value from the time-node into the mixer did not change at all, the displayed colour stayed the same.

**the main-question:**

**What do I have to change in order to make the time-node run from start-frame to end-frame ?**

Comment: To make snapshots (or screen  grabs) of any window in blender press Ctrl+F3

Comment: thank you, I tried, but blender crushed every time I do this.

Comment: can you share your file?

Comment: I do not have no file, at least I have no model or sculpture, only the node-graph, or do you mean sth. else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Time node](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/input/time.html) just like you have pictured in your question. If you press <kbd>F12</kbd> on different frames you will see that the color changes.

However it does not work well (and crashes blender sometimes) because you have only specified a color, nothing else for the output. You need a *size* for the output.

You can do that by mixing in anyone of following nodes: *Render Layer*, *Image*, or *Mask*.
Note the two selected nodes in the image below.
The node supplying the size (in my case the *Mask* node) must be plugged in to an additional *Mix* node. That mix node should have the factor set to 0 if the mask is in the bottom socket, or 1 if it is in the top. That way only your color gets rendered.

[image: compositing nodes]

[image: animated gif]

Comment: thx, what program did you use to capture the screen ?

Comment: @David I get same results whether pluging the mask node in the upper or lower socket and then I see no difference to my answer... Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Here is the meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred I use [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: @poor You used green and red, I used green and *blue*. Joking aside, I did not understand your answer when I wrote this one. I see now that they are basically the same. (the socket position doesn't make a difference) Sorry if I bothered you. If it helps, I UVed yours.

Comment: Hehe! I really appreciate your colors, awesome :) As always, Thanks @David! I'm interested in why it's hard to understand my answer. I thought it's a good idea to focus on how to get the composite first. Don't want to wasting your time, but if you've got a tip for future answers, please let me know. Thanks again. UVed back ;)

Comment: @poor not a waste of my time at all. I think the main problem was me, I read it too fast. This is (what I think) happened: I skimmed over your first sentence (skipping the first image), then read the part about animating the val, and saw the image with the val animated.

What I would change in your answer is to make it more clear that you have two *different* solutions there. Add a <hr> (in markdown just `---` on a line of its own) in between the two parts.  I would make the images more different (at my first glance I thought they were the same) But defiantly differentiate the two answers.

Answer (score 5):

The idea of the *Compositor* is editing some kind of **Input**. Either the **rendered result** via *Render Layer Node* or an arbitrary **image** from your hard drive via *Image Node*.

At the moment it's only possible to set up an **empty plate** in the compositor via *Mask Node*.

[image]
*256x256px 'canvas' - automatic animation via Time Node*

**Note:** It's not necessary to use a *Time Node* (in your case), because it's also possible to animate the `Fac` value of the *Mix Node*, related: [Is it possible Animate the Compositor node parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34660/is-it-possible-animate-the-compositor-node-parameters/34665#34665)

[image]
*256x256px 'canvas' - `Fac` value animation*

Answer (score 2):

To animate the factor on a mixe node you don't need a time node.

Go to frame 1 and set an initial value. Create a keyframe.
Move to frame 100, set the ending value for the node and add another keyframe.

[image]